# Produce a CFG for $\{a^ib^j \mid i<j\}$

Tags: finite-automata, context-free

How do I go about producing the context-free grammar for something like $\{a^i b^j \mid i<j\}$?

If it was $i=j$, then it's simple. But for something like this, is there a process to achieve it, or does one rely on intuition and practice?

Comment: Hint: write $j = i+k$, where $k \geq 1$.